# How to get name of cell that quantity is the largest?

Tags: excel, xls, xlsx

I have specific collumn:

[image]

I want to get "yes" in other cell, becouse quantity of apperance of this item is the largest. I do not know this is the rigth place to ask this question. Any ideas?

Comment: can't you just type it? You need to provide more context of the problem

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to add a label to ColumnA and create a PivotTable without totals for columns, say in G1, with the label dragged to ROWS and VALUES then:

```
 =INDEX(G:G,MATCH(MAX(H:H),H:H,0))
```